# Tensorflow Js No backend found in registery blazeface

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to know if there is some face on an image and so I'm using tensorflow JS with blazeface model. But after getting the code an error appear:

```
Error: No backend found in registry.
    at Engine.getSortedBackends (/home/saren/project/spark/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:2928:19)
    at Engine.initializeBackendsAndReturnBest (/home/saren/project/spark/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:2937:35)
    at Engine.get [as backend] (/home/saren/project/spark/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:2743:31)
    at Engine.makeTensor (/home/saren/project/spark/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:3268:35)
    at makeTensor (/home/saren/project/spark/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:4087:19)
    at tensor (/home/saren/project/spark/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:4136:12)
    at Object.decodeWeights (/home/saren/project/spark/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:4400:27)
    at GraphModel.loadSync (/home/saren/project/spark/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter/dist/tf-converter.node.js:7410:34)
    at GraphModel.<anonymous> (/home/saren/project/spark/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter/dist/tf-converter.node.js:7385:52)
    at step (/home/saren/project/spark/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter/dist/tf-converter.node.js:77:23)
```

This is my code (I copy past it from the documentation):

```
module.exports = {
    blazeface: require('@tensorflow-models/blazeface'),

    async detectFace(imageLink) {
        const model = await this.blazeface.load();
        const returnTensors = false;
        const predictions = await model.estimateFaces(imageLink, returnTensors);
        if (predictions.length > 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < predictions.length; i++) {
            const start = predictions[i].topLeft;
            const end = predictions[i].bottomRight;
            const size = [end[0] - start[0], end[1] - start[1]];
        
            // Render a rectangle over each detected face.
            ctx.fillRect(start[0], start[1], size[0], size[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Remember that the error came from the following line `const model = await this.blazeface.load();`

So a lot of people are talking about the version so this is an exemple of my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@tensorflow-models/blazeface": "0.0.6",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^3.0.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu": "^3.0.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl": "^3.0.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-converter": "^3.0.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-core": "^3.0.0"
  }
```

I'm using Node version 14.8.0 and npm version 6.14.7.
This code should work on a server and so I don't want it to work in front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you can do two things.

Install @tensorflow/tfjs-node and use `tf: require("@tensorflow/tfjs-node"),`
Or you can use `this.tf.getBackend();` (even with this `tf: require("@tensorflow/tfjs")`)